# Nearby Messages API not scanning beacons

Tags: android, eddystone, google-nearby

I am trying to scan the Eddystone UID beacons registered with my project on Google Beacon Platform using this tutorial:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/hello-beacons/

Somehow, the app is unable to find any beacons. I checked the onHandleIntent() of the background service and found that onFound() is never called. However, the code successfully enters the onHandleIntent() and I'm subscribed to nearby.

I've double checked these things:

1. My beacons are registered with the same project whose API_KEY I'm using in android_manifest.xml.
2. My beacons are successfully scanned by Beacon Tools app and even in Nearby Discoveries (for Nearby Notification Attachment).

Am I missing out something here?

I see a couple of questions informing the same issue but couldn't find a suitable answer for the same.

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen [get-beacon-messages](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-beacon-messages) doc?